# Installed phpunit using composer but still says to install using apt-get

Tags: apt, software-installation, composer

I have installed composer globally on my Ubuntu12.04 machine.

I can confirm it because it is in the `~/.composer/vendor` directory and is included in global composer.json.

My problem is whenever I try to run `phpunit` it gives the following

```
The program 'phpunit' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing: 
sudo apt-get install phpunit
```

EDIT:

I am following the instructions found [here](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html)

Comment: I would assume `phpunit` is not on your path. You can confirm this with the command `which phpunit` it won't be found if it's not on your path.

Comment: Then you should try it: `sudo apt-get install phpunit`

Comment: @ElderGeek tried `which phpunit` but there was not output on my terminal

Comment: If it was installed globally, your system would have caught that already.  Exactly how did you install it?

Comment: @Faron I used this command `composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=4.5.*"
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have skipped `sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit` when following the instructions.

the result is that `phpunit` is not on your path.

You have 2 choices.

1) Do the step you missed, (recommended)

2) Hack things in such a way that phpunit is found on your path by another method.

If any of this is unclear, drop me a comment and I'll do my best to elaborate.

Comment: By path did you mean `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: Based on the instructions you say you followed and the command I think you skipped, the file phpunit.phar is moved to /usr/local/bin which should be on your path and renamed to phpunit simultaneously. this will allow running `phpunit` from the command line.

Comment: This is weird that installing it globally using composer didn't work for me. So I just followed your previous comment, and used the phpunit.phar, thanks

Comment: It's not that strange that skipping a key command in the instructions would result in a problem. Regardless, I'm glad your problem is resolved. :-)

Comment: Just to add, once you have the phpunit.phar you don't need to install it globally using composer.

Answer (score 0):

If `which` does not return a path, it means that your system is not seeing it at all, which also means that `phpunit` is not globally recognized and is not part of system's PATH.

To have it to be recognized, you need to have it to be inside the system as top level.  Best shot is to execute this command `sudo apt-get install phpunit`.  Always use this command as it'll save your headache.

But if you are installing a package that isn't available in apt-get repository, then you will want to configure the package for a specific path.  `./configure --path=/usr` or `./configure --path=/usr/share`.

Avoid using `/usr/local`.

Hope you tackle this down.  Good luck.